# how to update multiple tables with pdo php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to be able to update two tables with one Update query. There are plenty of answers but I can't still pinpoint the one that helps me. I want to allow the admin user to update teams and scores only. The Scores tables have the team names as HomeTeam and AwayTeam. They are foreign keys to the Teams table. After several hours of searching, I thought to ask for your help because I don't seem to be able to find the error "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined". I hope you can help me! I'm using PDO, PHP, MySQL Here's my code :

```
if (isset($_POST["Update"])) {
   update($_POST["ID"]);
}
function update($id) {
   
    try {
     
      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $GLOBALS['servername'] . ";dbname=e0912343_Fixtures", 
      $GLOBALS['username'], $GLOBALS['password']);
     
      $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

      $statement = $conn->prepare("UPDATE Scores AS s 
        
        Teams AS ht LEFT JOIN s ON s.HomeTeam=ht.TeamName 
        
        Teams AS at LEFT JOIN s ON s.AwayTeam=at.TeamName

        SET  s.HT_score=:HT_score, s.AT_score=:AT_score 
       
        ht.TeamName=:TeamName, at.TeamName=:TeamName                

        WHERE s.FixtureID=" . $id);
      
      $statement->bindValue(":HT_score", $_POST["HT_score"]);
      
      $statement->bindValue(":AT_score", $_POST["AT_score"]);       
      
      $statement->bindValue(":ht.HomeTeam", $_POST["HomeTeam"]);  
      
      $statement->bindValue(":at.AwayTeam", $_POST["AwayTeam"]);  
        
      $result = $statement->execute();
      
      if ($result) {
          
         $GLOBALS['message'] = "The records were updated";
         
      } else {
          
         $GLOBALS['message'] = "The records were not updated";
      }
   }
   catch(PDOException $e) {
      
       echo "We are sorry. A problem occured4: " . $e->getMessage();
   }

   $conn = null;
}
```

Comment: You are confusing things. Just look at how you are doing it with `:HT_score` and `:AT_score`. Do the same with `HomeTeam` and `AwayTeam`

Comment: Also why not make a parameter for `$id` like all the others?

Comment: @B001ᛦ thank you for your comment. As I'm already quite confused, I was not able to make your suggestion work. I have opted to read some more, I'm still quite green on the subject. Many thanks for your time any way :)

Comment: `SET ....ht.TeamName=:HomeTeam .... at.TeamName=:AwayTeam` then on bindvalue `:HomeTeam` and `:AwayTeam`